# What is a biased sensor?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I am working on a 3 Lead amperometric cell in Potentiostat configuration (CE, RE and WE) and I found the word "Biased sensor" and "Bias voltage" all over the datasheet. My question is:

- What is a biased sensor ?
- Why shall we inject a Bias voltage in a biased sensor ?

Link: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmp91000.pdf

Comment: Same words mean different things in different context, you should add a link to the datasheet if possible, or quote some relevant text to give us a bit more stuff to work with.

Comment: A data sheet link is necessary.

Comment: Edited. I added the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Design of Electronics for Electrochemical Gas 
Sensors](https://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2014/08/A1A-EC_SENSORS_AN2-Design-of-Electronics-for-EC-Sensors-V4.pdf):

> For sensors which have 3 electrodes, (the majority of sensors  for  detecting  toxic  gases  and  EC410 Oxygen sensor), the circuit required is known as a potentiostatic circuit. This  circuit can either have the sensing and reference electrodes at the same potential (non-biased) or the sensing and reference held at different voltages (a biased sensor).

and

> The purpose of the sensor bias circuit (potentiostat) is to maintain the potential of the sensing electrode at a constant level with respect to the reference electrode. This is done by adjusting the voltage of a third ‘counter’ electrode.

As to *why* one would do that, I think you might need to ask over on [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/), however, for the case of an SGX EC410 oxygen sensor, user [Viktor Scherf](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/100564/viktor-scherf) wrote in a [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217551/problem-with-biased-circuit-for-oxygen-sensor-sgx-ec410?rq=1#comment465760_217551) that:

> The bias voltage is needed for chemical redaction of oxygen.